# Google rank 1, but not ranked at all in Bing, Yahoo or DuckDuckGo

Tags: seo, search

I'm using the Epic browser and a proxy (based in my country), to do searches for my website. I'm doing this so search engines can't estimate where I am based and suggest my own website

In Google, for my main key phrase I am ranked 1.

But for Bing, Yahoo and DuckDuckGo my website doesn't even appear in the first few pages. Worse than this, when I search for my website it is not appearing either.

In Yahoo, if I do a site:example.co.uk search it only shows one page of my multi-page site and it says this:

> 301 Moved Permanently . The document has been permanently moved.

In my .htaccess file, I do have some code "turning on" or "moving" (not sure what it is called) visitors from http to https and from non-www to www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost(?::\d+)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Is adding the www causing a problem in Bing, Yahoo and DuckDuckGo? But not in Google? I've checked my site in Google Search Console and most of my pages are being indexed.

My site is about 12 years old and I've never noticed SEO problems before. The .htaccess code is about 9 months old. I doubt I'd have had this problem for 9 months without realising it. So I'm unsure why I now have a problem.

Comment: For Bing, have you looked in [Webmaster Tools](https://www.bing.com/webmasters/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me